# removing blank spaces from email submission

Tags: php, email, strip, submission

I want to create a contact form that has an email field where the user can’t enter any white space, for example: `test@example.com m`
I am using a spam scrubbing function to clean user inputs.
I am using my variable like so: `$email = strip_tags($scrubbed['email']);`

How can I add something like this: `$email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email);`
to the existing `$email = strip_tags($scrubbed['email']);`?

I tried 
`$email = (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email)(strip_tags($scrubbed['email'])));` and all sorts of variations to that. They didn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

You should strongly consider using filter_var() for email address validation.

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)) {
    // validation failed
}
```

Trying to fix input for the end user can lead to unexpected results and still not give you a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do it in two lines?

`$email = strip_tags($scrubbed['email']);`

`$email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email);`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$email = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strip_tags($scrubbed['email']));
```